# notification manager crash android aacplayer app

Tags: android

Hi i have my app aacplayer works good in my galaxy s3 but in a galaxy ace with android 2.3.4 my app crash but if i remove the notification manager from code then it works perfec.

heres my notificaction manager code:

```
public void playerMetadata(final String key, final String value) {
        TextView tv = null;

        if ("StreamTitle".equals(key) || "icy-name".equals(key)
                || "icy-description".equals(key)) {
            tv = txtMetaTitle;
        } else if ("icy-url".equals(key)) {
            tv = txtMetaUrl;
        } else
            return;

        final TextView ftv = tv;

        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ftv.setText(value);
                int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                int icon = R.drawable.notificacion;
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                CharSequence tickerText = "Reproduciendo...";
                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,
                        when);
                RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.notification);
                contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, R.drawable.notificacion);
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title_text, txtMetaTitle
                        .getText().toString());

                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.message_text, txtMetaUrl
                        .getText().toString());

                notification.contentView = contentView;
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AACPlayerActivity.this,
                        Principal.class);

                // Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,
                // Principal.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

                // PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                // 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            }
        });
    }
```

i dont know why works good in the galaxy s3 but not in the galaxy ace how i can fix that.

thank you very much.

edit:

logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16846): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.spoledge.aacplayer: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=com.spoledge.aacplayer id=1 tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x2))
```

if i add this in my code:

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, 
txtMetaTitle.getText().toString(), 
txtMetaUrl.getText().toString(), contentIntent);
```

notification works good no issues, but i need to show the notification with this:

```
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title_text, txtMetaTitle
                        .getText().toString());

                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.message_text, txtMetaUrl
                        .getText().toString());
```

that txtmetatitle field have a marquee but if add that line posted before notification.setLatestEvent, works without crash but i cannot make the marquee run correctly

Comment: Examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: i just added the logcat thank u

Comment: Look up for other error or exception (maybe warnings), it's saying that the notification couldn't be created correctly